# Is there a package to write slide and narration contents at the same time but produces each separately at the final?

Tags: beamer, presentations

Writing a presentation frame and its corresponding narration at the same time can help us to reduce the complexity.

In other words, I need a mechanism as follows (it is a pseudo-code)

```
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{slide}
%slide content to show
\end{slide}
\begin{narration}
%narration goes here.
\end{narration}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Definition}
\begin{slide}
%slide content to show
\end{slide}
\begin{narration}
%narration goes here.
\end{narration}
\end{frame}

%etc...
```

Is there a package to write slide and narration contents at the same time but produces each separately at the final?

Comment: As Martin says below, this is possible using the Article Mode where it is possible to divide your document into "stuff _inside_ frames" and "stuff _outside_ frames" and process the two separately.  However, that's not _quite_ the scheme you describe as both your sets of stuff are inside frames.  If that is what you want, it would be very easy to implement but I don't know of a package that already does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look in the beameruserguide. The beamer class supports an "article version" that can co-exist in the same file as your slides. The relevant section in the manual is named

> Creating Handouts Using the Article Mode